# ClassNotFoundException at startup of JavaFX application on OpenJDK 8

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to run a JavaFX application (originally developed with OracleJDK 8) on OpenJDK 8.

According to [this comparison table](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/jdk-comparison-matrix/), the Azul Zulu JDK and the Amazon Corretto JDK do include JavaFX/OpenJFX support.

However, when starting the application, I get the following exception (same in both Zulu 8.40.0.25 and Corretto 8.222.10.3; OS is Windows 7 64-bit):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.HostServicesFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.HostServicesDelegate.lambda$getInstance$0(HostServicesDelegate.java:52)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.HostServicesDelegate.getInstance(HostServicesDelegate.java:45)
        at javafx.application.HostServices.<init>(HostServices.java:52)
        at javafx.application.Application.getHostServices(Application.java:334)
        at de.saxsys.mvvmfx.cdi.MvvmfxCdiApplication.<init>(MvvmfxCdiApplication.java:57)
        at (my application).gui.AppRunner.<init>(AppRunner.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$7(LauncherImpl.java:819)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After that, the application seems to run normally, so I am unsure if there is a problem or not.

[This thread](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/issues/68) suggests that the issue is related to the `getHostServices()` method and has been fixed.

I also found [this (older) discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-June/019375.html) indicating that this is not an error and the exception should not be visible on the console.

Can anyone confirm that the exception can be safely ignored?
Does anyone know whether the mentioned fix has been or will eventually be included in the Zulu and/or Corretto builds?